# How does render link in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a little confused about render, not quite sure which path it chooses to link.

According to docs:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

we can have explicit link:

```
render "/u/apps/warehouse_app/current/app/views/products/show"
```

But, in /apps/view/layouts/application.html.erb if I have shims for _header and _footer, I have to go:

```
render 'layout/header'
```

so it looks for path starting from ../app/view/ then appends layout/_header.html.erb to fetch the file. But in the rule listed on rubyonrails.org using explicit link, indicated by leading /, has a path starting from the root folder (/u/apps/...).

So my question is when using render with leading / which is the starting director? Is it always root, and layout is just an exception to the rule?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss this point. The render method can also use a view that’s entirely outside of your application (perhaps you’re sharing views between two Rails applications):

```
render "/u/apps/warehouse_app/current/app/views/products/show"
```

Rails determines that this is a file render because of the leading slash character.

In general if you are adding a view file from another controller it takes as

```
render "prodcucts/show"
```

it will take the path till view folder automatically. And for layout you can same as above

```
render "layouts/header"
```

Comment: having the leading / renders from before root? like render /u/apps indicates that it your linking to show inside the u app, but say you are app u, can I link to /y/apps/...?

Comment: yes that's what I meant in first half that it can take the view from entirely outside app or from different app when you give link like /y/apps/...

Comment: is there is an example when this is actually useful?

Comment: @Saad think multiple apps communicating between each other. It shouldn't happen often, but perhaps you have different apps for your `backend` and `frontend`, or perhaps each site in the StackExchange network is its own app, but needs to grab the header at the top of the page from a single app? In these cases this could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
render '/layout/header'
```

Should just be

```
render 'layout/header'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion about the correct path is caused by the fact that you use the first `render` option to point to a layout file. This is not the way layouts are supposed to be used.

Instead you would use them like so:

```
render 'users/show', layout: 'mylayout'
```

In your case however, it seems like what you really want to use, are **[partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)**.

Something like this would work:

```
render 'shared/header'
```

With the file named `_header.html.erb`

Two important notes from the documentation:

> For content that is shared among all pages in your application, you can use partials directly from layouts.

and:

> A partial can use its own layout file, just as a view can use a layout. For example, you might call a partial like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "link_area", :layout => "graybar" %>
```